# java mysql : table row as object containing string

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, string, jdbc

I create a class (Employee) with just data members in java to match the row of employee table.
String Name, int Age, double Salary and so on.

Next I create an array of objects employee `emp[]=new employee[50]` with fixed dimension of 50 and read some rows of data from mySQL DB and store in this object array one by one.
This object array is then returned by a method to the calling method.
Next, I want to process this object array in a while loop like this

```
while(!emp[arraycounter].Name.equals(""))
```

I think, I am checking for the first element of the object array where the Name is empty.

This throws a `NullPointerException`. What am I missing ?
In fact I want to be able to pass around the elements of this object array to methods, which are declared to accept an object of the employee class as a parameter.

Sat

Comment: Add the full (relevant) code and the stacktrace.

Comment: Maybe you compare "" with null?

Comment: I think you need to check if the result set  next item is not null then check for name if it is null or blank !

Answer (score -1):

For exemple if you have only 35 rows in your database, when you do emp[35], the employee is null. So when you do emp[35].Name you get the NPE.
Some advice:

1/ use lower case for attributes

2/better user "".equals(string) than string.equals("") to avoid NPE

3/Just use a list instead of an array:

```
List<Employee> employees= new ArrayList<Employee>();
employees.add(The data extracted form db)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. There isn't enough information available in the question anyway, so I don't see why you even try to answer it.

Comment: He asked why he had an NPE. So i explain him why he gets it. Not bad if YOU dont have enougth informations. But thanks for -1....

Comment: You can't know the exact reason with the information we currently have. Your answer contains "for example", which shows that you don't know it for sure.

Comment: Next time, please ask for clarification in comments before providing an answer. :) This is more helpful for the OP, clearer for the system and moderators, and results in a shorter edit/solution cycle. Thanks for trying to help tho!!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you have to include the full code for us to analyze.

Second, let me be a little bit annoying - do not access properties from the outside. Set them as private and create getName and setName methods, and so on. This is a good practice.

Now, for your problem - you are either not initializing your objects or the properties within them. That is, in the employee constructor, you should have default values for all your properties (such as `Name="";`) and before reading the data, you should initialize the whole array (like `for(i=0;i<50;i++) emp[i]=new Employee();`).

You probably missed one of the two. It is impossible to say which one without the code.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity: would someone explain to me why I got two downvotes? I would like to learn what was the mistake I made in my answer.

Comment: It seems that with answers you got downvotes and with "Add the full (relevant) code and the stacktrace" you got upvotes..

Comment: Thank you for the lesson @Erwan C., but it seems quite dogmatic to me. If I have an idea that might help another user even though his description is not complete, I should refrain from helping just because he does not post his code? I understand the value of good descriptions and the need of code to understand fully the problem (hence my first paragraph), but is the obsession really necessary?

Comment: " If I have an idea that might help another user even though his description is not complete" --->yes i totally agree and i learnt it the hard way too but i can understand that if everydbody start to give answers without information it ll be hard for new comers to sort them

Comment: Well, thank you for the lesson. It is always important to learn the thought process of a community. I will try to adhere to the standards in the future.